# Requests served counter not getting incremented in JAX-RS (Jersey) web service

Tags: java, rest, servlets

Disclaimer: This is just a test I was running and not trying to get reliable requests served counter.

Since Jersey is built on top of servlets, I'm assuming that a servlet is shared among all requests. So I wrote a very basic class:

```
@Path("/id")
public class TestIdGeneration {

    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response serveRequest() {
        Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(String.valueOf(counter.incrementAndGet()));
        return response.build();
    }
}
```

I was assuming that with every GET request the counter will be updated by one. But evertime I make a get request I get back the value 1. I checked the Response Headers to make sure the request wasn't cached. Here are the complete response headers:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 00:12:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Why isn't the counter being updated with every GET request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [jax-rs documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.17/jax-rs.html#d4e483):

> By default the life-cycle of root resource classes is per-request,
>   namely that a new instance of a root resource class is created every
>   time the request URI path matches the root resource.

So the reported behavior is expected since a new instance is created for each request. Try declaring your counter as `static` instead.

Comment: Thank you David. This is very interesting, now we only need to worry about concurrent access only to static members. We can get away with using a non-static HashMap instead of a ConcurrentHashMap.